# (Broad level) Classification of ghosts in Hinduism

Tags: scripture, evil, classification, ghosts

This question is intended to know about *broad level* classification only. Further classification is *not* needed.

In English language, words may not exist for each category of ghosts. So I am using an umbrella term "ghost" to cover all such beings.

I heard and know the names of Bhoota, Pretha, Pisacha only.

Are these three only the classes of ghosts? If no, what is the broad level classification of ghosts?

Comment: @Archit makes them seem less like classifications and more like different euphemisms for the same thing.

Comment: Just heard, it's based on age of the person who dies. Like as i heard Munja (of a small kid) , Khiss (of a unmarried ). Or based on wishes remaining. I just guess these are not true classifications.